# angular ng-click add http data inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I use $http.get php data in ng-repeat is correct,but I have a problem when  ng-click to add push php second page data in ng-repeat ,but it  not work .

Any suggestions ? thanks.

***I did not write very clear ,  i mean  when click  button , i want get ats01.php?page=2 data, add  ats01.php?page=1 data  in li ng-repeat,  i don't want get page2 data replace page1 data,just like jquery $('#ul01').append (html) method;  thank your answer it .***

script.js

```js
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp');
var myurl="http://192.168.5.9/"
 
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get(myurl+"php/ats01.php?page=1")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
     $scope.myur=myurl;
             
    $scope.add = function() {
        $http.get(myurl+"php/ats01.php?page=2")
     .success(function (response) { 
       $scope.names.push(response.records);
         });
           };
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html >
<head >
      <script src="anjs/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-app="scotchApp"  >
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
         <p ><a href="#/phones/{{x.TA001}}" > <img ng-src="{{myur}}img/{{x.TA006}}"> </a><small>{{x.TA002}}&nbsp;{{x.TA003}}&nbsp;{{x.TA004}}&nbsp;{{x.TA012}}</small> </p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <p>    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first time you are assigning record in the list

```
$scope.names = response.records;
```

But in click you are pushing same data instead of assigning

```
$scope.names.push(response.records);
```

If you push instead of assign it'll create a index and push whole data into that index.

Convert this

```
$scope.names.push(response.records);
```

to this

```
$scope.names=$scope.names.concat(response.records);
```

Comment: I did not write very clear ,  i mean  when click  button , i want get ats01.php?page=2 data, add  ats01.php?page=1 data  in <li ng-repeat>,  i don't want get page2 data replace page1 data, thank your answer it .

Comment: $scope.names=$scope.names.concat(response.records)   is ok ,thank u very much , its helpful ..